# Button in each row of a table dash plotly python

Tags: python, dataframe, python-2.7, plotly-dash

I’m trying to create a table with an "Edit" button for every row that will open a modal to edit some informations.

| left | center | right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | EDIT |
| One | ONE | EDIT |

How can I fix each button in a row ?

Didn't find some examples in this topic.. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by fix? Do you want to create the buttons within the column on the right?